# Is PHP function names case-sensitive or not?

Tags: php

I am from Java background. 
In Java, every method has case-sensitive while calling. But in PHP, I didn't see the case-sensitive function name while calling the functions.

```
class Sample {

    ...
    ...

    function sampleFunction() {

       ....
       ....

    }

}

$obj = new Sample();
$obj->sampleFunction(); /* Proper call with function name */
$obj->samplefunction(); /* It should show undefined function error but it also calls sampleFunction()  */
```

Can anyone clear my doubt why this is also called even non-case sensitive function name. And please give me how to restrict in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can force case sensitivity beyond good coding practices from your side. This is just another one of PHP's retarded "features"

Comment: They're [not case-sensitive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php). And that's just how the language was designed. You can always use a different language though.

Comment: Is this question still regarded as off topic? It has a clear answer. Not that it needs more answers though.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

They are case insensitive, see this:

> Note: Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good
>   form to call functions as they appear in their declaration.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: +1, for bringing in the content from the manual.

Comment: This is the accepted answer but it says, "any user defined function i think is case sensitive" when the correct answer is that function names are case _insensitive_.

Comment: This question is currently the top hit on Google for "php function case sensitive", and the accepted answer (when I came here) incorrectly said that it's case sensitive. I've submitted an edit to correct that.

Answer (score 17):

Functions are not case sensitive, Variables are case sensitive.

you can read more info from manual :

http://fr.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: Good that you've also mentioned that variables *are* case sensitive :)