# Difference between DOMDocument (with capitals) and DomDocument?

Tags: php

I just noticed that in my code I have both something like:

```
$domdoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
```

and

```
$domdoc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
```

... apparently since I've copypasted from different examples.

However, if I remember correctly, PHP is case-sensitive, so `DOMDocument` should not be the same as `DomDocument`?! Although, when I run the code with both instances in PHP 5.5.9, it seems to work - no complaints are raised...

So, can anyone explain whether `DOMDocument` is alias of `DomDocument` (or vice versa) - or are these similar, but different classes?

Comment: Thanks @Daan - had no idea about that; feel free to post that as an answer, I'll accept it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273941/php-case-sensitivity

Comment: class names themselves AREN'T case sensitive, but if you're using an autoloader and running on a case-sensitive file system, then you may run into case issues, if the autoloader doesn't normalize cases.

Comment: But don't make a habit of mixing case on class names. Sooner or later it will cause mistakes attempting the same with array keys or variable names, which are case-_sensitive_ unlike functions and classes.

Comment: Conventionally (inasmuch as PHP has any convention) keep your functions lower-cased and classes "studly cased" (begin with upper, use an upper for the start of new words). DOMDocument is an ambiguous one because it begins with an acronym --  you'll see it done both ways as you've noticed already. Be consistent within your own code however you choose to case it (I recommend doing it as [in its documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) as `DOMDocument`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is case insensitive for the class naming.

Comment: Thanks @Daan - will accept this as soon as the timer expires... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

DomDocument is a powerful library of PHP-5 to create XML.
DOMDocument Represents an entire HTML or XML document; serves as the root of the document tree.

Comment: Thanks @Leo, but I'm not sure whether this distinction is correct, any links or an example to back it up? In any case, in my OP I can instantiate a class object regardless if I use `new DOMDocument` or `new DomDocument`, and I don't really have to refer to the root ?!