# Why am I getting PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyClass' not found?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, namespaces, autoloader

This works:

```
class MyClass {
    public $prop = 'hi';
}

class Container {
    static protected $registry = [];
    public static function get($key){
        if(!array_key_exists($key, static::$registry)){
            static::$registry[$key] = new $key;
        }
        return static::$registry[$key];
    }
}

$obj = Container::get('MyClass');
echo $obj->prop;
```

> hi

But when I try to break it out into individual files, I get an error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'MyClass' not found in /nstest/src/Container.php:9

This is line 9:

```
static::$registry[$key] = new $key;
```

What's crazy is that I can hard code it, and it works, so I know the namespace is correct.

```
static::$registry[$key] = new MyClass;
```

> hi

Obviously I don't want to hard code it because I need dynamic values. I've also tried:

```
$key = $key::class;
static::$registry[$key] = new $key;
```

But that gives me this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch

I'm at a loss. [Clone these files to reproduce](https://github.com/scratchers/nstest):

```
.
├── composer.json
├── main.php
├── src
│   ├── Container.php
│   └── MyClass.php
├── vendor
│   └── ...
└── works.php
```

Don't forget the autoloader.

```
composer dumpautoload
```

## composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "scratchers\\nstest\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

## main.php

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use scratchers\nstest\Container;

$obj = Container::get('MyClass');
echo $obj->prop;
```

## src/Container.php

```
namespace scratchers\nstest;

class Container {
    static protected $registry = [];
    public static function get($key){
        if(!array_key_exists($key, static::$registry)){
            static::$registry[$key] = new $key;
        }
        return static::$registry[$key];
    }
}
```

## src/MyClass.php

```
namespace scratchers\nstest;

class MyClass {
    public $prop = 'hi';
}
```

Comment: `new ClassName` looks for the class relative to the current namespace, `new $classname` does not.

Comment: @tkausl hmm that makes sense, so what's the solution?

Comment: Use the full classname in your variable (i.e. `\scratchers\nstest\MyClass`) or better `MyClass::class` (which yields the full classname)

Comment: @tkausl thanks! That did the trick :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Thanks to @tkausl](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/67258565?noredirect=1), I was able to get around dynamic relative namespacing by passing the fully qualified name in as the variable.

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use scratchers\nstest\Container;
use scratchers\nstest\MyClass;

$obj = Container::get(MyClass::class);
echo $obj->prop;
```

> hi

Comment: Also, make sure your use statement capital or small letters make the difference.

Comment: @prosti actually class names are not case sensitive in php https://stackoverflow.com/a/33273959/4233593