# Because my case sensitive does not work on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) on vagrant

Tags: php, vagrant, case-sensitive

I have a virtual machine mounted from the vagrant with Official Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) builds, I set up an environment with PHP 5.6, Mysql and apache 2 in this virtual machine, however I did some tests with PHP, and I noticed that the case sensitive does not work, I already had some Problems in file calls in the production environment because of case sensitive, it would help me a lot to be able to identify this in the development, does anyone know what could be happening?

index.php

```
include_once "Filecamelcase.php";

$teste = new teste();

echo $teste->teste();
```

FileCamelCase.php

```
class Teste {

    function Teste(){
        return "teste";
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using autoload from composer? If it has a class map, could ignore some file paths.

Comment: No, I just used PHP structured to do the tests. And in my production application I do not use composer.

Comment: Show us your tests

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Linux filepaths are case sensitive. Class/methods/functions names aren't. https://3v4l.org/0pLmL

Comment: I understand perfectly, I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented. A Linux filepath is case sensitive.

On the other hand, PHP code interpretation is independent of operating system. PHP has his own rules for that behavior even if these rules are a bit annoying or mysterious. Basically:

**Case insensitive**

> functions, class constructors, class methods, keywords and constructs
>   (if, else, null, foreach, echo etc.)

As you can see in the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33273959/1628790