# Is there a readdirectory function in php

Tags: php

I came across following piece of code while reading a php code :

```
$files = array();
foreach ( $folders as $fold ) {
                if ( ! is_dir( $fold ) ) {
                    continue;
                }
                $files = array_merge( $files, readdirectrory( $folder ) );
            }
```

But I did not find any related to readdirectory in code base so I search google if function belongs to php, but no luck. Can anybody have any idea.

Comment: Here are various ways of reading directories. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php

Comment: yeah, but above function works and return all files exist in a directory . What I am curious is how? I did not find any function names `readdirectory`

Comment: yeah, but above function works and return all files exist in a directory . What I am curious is how? I did not find any function names `readdirectory`

Comment: readdirectrory must be in your code some where. The $folders array is the list you  are searching through.

Comment: In the  foreach you have $fold but latter you use $folder that is not assigned.

Comment: @JasonK yes that is $fold in function , I mistakenly written above.

Comment: I have grep in whole project directory `grep -r 'readdirectrory' . `

Comment: @JasonK found a function name 'readDirectory' I did not know that php is case insensitive :-|

Comment: Some of it is. Some of it is not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273941/php-case-sensitivity