# Laravel Class/Controller level variable doesnt get update from Method

Tags: php, laravel, variables

I have this variable on class/Controller level `$songRating` and i am calling this method through ajax, when i first time call this method it runs the `if` block which is good. and now `$songRating` should be `1`.
But this is not a case. When i call this method it again runs the `if` block. Dont know why :/

```
public $songRating;
public function GetHighRatedSong()
{
        if($this->songRating == null){
            $this->songRating=1;
        }else{
            $this->songRating=2;
        }

        return response()->json($this->songRating);
}
```

Comment: if by the next time you call this method you mean the next "request" then it really wouldn't matter what you set any instance variable to before as these are all new instance variables at this point

Comment: im from c# background and in that we are allowed to do this.if we have any class level variable then after changing its value from method that variable saves this variable for a single request.. im calling this method using ajax..

Comment: As lagbox said, you should save the $this->songRating attribute somewhere (may be update the Model if this is inside a Model object). In PHP, each request runs in a completely different thread, it will not know what happened in your previous request unless you save the data somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Try with Replacing

```
$this->songrating=1;
```

to

```
$this->songRating=1; # song+Rating != song+rating
```

> Read [PHP & Case Sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33273959/4595675)

Comment: My bad..Its a typo when i was writing code in StackOverflow.. but in actual code i have $this->songRating=1 with uppercase R

Comment: wrap `$this->songRating='1';` with quotes

Comment: sorry bro.. private didnt help :/

Answer (score 0):

It's because everytime you call that function or make a new instantiation to the class, it will automatically reset to it's original value. Try to use [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container)