# PHPUnit trait not found after updating composer.json

Tags: symfony, composer-php, phpunit

Original composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [ "/tests/" ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": { "tests\\": "tests/" }
}
```

New composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "TOTO\\": "src/TOTO"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php" ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [ "/tests/" ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "files": [
        "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
    ]
},
```

My trait is defined in `tests\TOTO\Services\InvokeMethodTrait` and is called by other tests such as `tests\TOTO\Services\ConversationServiceTest`, since that change for optimizing the autoloader I get `Fatal error: Trait 'tests\TOTO\Services\InvokeMethodTrait' not found in /var/www/symfony/tests/TOTO/Services/ConversationServiceTest.php on line 17`. It was working properly before and I didn't change anything in the related classes.

Any idea?

Comment: would this discussion on github help ? https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original part of `composer.json` had:

```
"psr-4": { "tests\\": "tests/" }
```

and the new one:

```
"psr-4": {
    "Tests\\": "tests/"
}
```

There can be seen a change in case for `tests` namespace. That is not an issue for PHP (natively) since namespaces and classes are case-insensitive (great answer with summary on PHP case sensitivity https://stackoverflow.com/a/33273959/5264262). But composer's autoloader receives that unknown class name as string and resolves all that fully qualified class names to some paths to `require` a file, so the process is case sensitive. There was some discussion on the opened issue at https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2767 concerning the topic.

The final point is: our namespaces and class naming in composer.json should be case-sensitive compliant.