# String type casing in php, is it string or String?

Tags: php, php-7, type-hinting, type-declaration

What is the official name for the php string type?

Is it 'string' like c#, or 'String' like Java, or either?

I could not find it in http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

I want to use it to strict type my function

```
function getImageName() : string;
```

or

```
function getImageName() : String;
```

Comment: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-type-hinting.html

Comment: The case does not matter. `STRING` works as well as `string` or `sTrInG`.
But I'd always use the lower variant (`string`). This is the preferred way to dot it.

Comment: Interesting. I never knew PHP was case insensitive in some cases. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273941/php-case-sensitivity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As PHP is a [partially case sensitive language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273941/php-case-sensitivity) and, in particular, keywords are NOT case sensitive, the case doesn't matter for built-in type names. **Both `string` and `String` will work as type declaration (aka 'type hint').**

The official documentation mentions the lowercase variants, so it's *probably* a good idea to use lowercase keywords as code style — just like most PHP code styles use `foreach` and not `Foreach`, for example.

P.S. You can find the documentation on the [PHP Function arguments page, 'Type declarations' section](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).