# String parameters case on php

Tags: php

In `php 7+` when I use string parameters , the correct way its `String` or `string`

```
 public function my_function(string $parameters):string{

       return "foo";
 }
```

or

```
 public function my_function(String $parameters):String{

       return "foo";
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String type casing in php, is it string or String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150817/string-type-casing-in-php-is-it-string-or-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP there is no difference between `String` and `string` on definitions.

Most common is the second, `string`

```php
$stringValue = "Hello world";
echo gettype($stringValue);
```

```php
string
```