# laravel orm : How to treat obsessive-compulsive disorder

Tags: laravel

**chinese description：**

laravel orm的命名规范对强迫症来说简直是一种灾难，为什么会有这样的设计。。

数据库字段设计成小写字母+下划线，例如order_item表中有个字段goods_name

那么laravel代码中，就得这样写：$orderItem->goods_name

驼峰和全小写混合，强迫症表示实在受不了啊。。。受不了。。。受不了。。。

**english description：**
for example: I have a table named order_item and the table have a column named goods_name
in laravel orm I will write code such as: $orderItem->goods_name

the hump naming with the whole lower case，，，，

why why why

why the laravel design so。why not design like：$orderItem->goodsName

I am going nuts.

Comment: uhh, this question is not exactly something you want to drop to stackoverflow. please contact Taylor Otwell himself or just bug people on [#laravel in freenode](https://webchat.freenode.net/). regarding the `$orderItem->goods_name`, you need to know the [case sensitivity on php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273941/php-case-sensitivity) itself also... lol.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column in your database name as snake_case you probably have the same case name in your object model.

What you could do is to modify your OrderItem model to define an assessor and append a new variable like this

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrderItem extends Model
{
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['goodsName'];

    /**
     * Get the administrator flag for the user.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getGoodsNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['goods_name'];
    }
}

/////
$model = OrderItem ::find(1);
dump($model->goodsName);
dd($model);
```