# What is the difference between String and string in php?

Tags: php, string

Is there a difference ?
I don't get it.
Or maybe a string is a class and
String is a reference to the System.string?
like in c#

Comment: types are case insensitive, there are no differences. You can even use `StRiNg` if you think it's funny

Comment: In php there is no such thing as String only string it's only case insensitive but now proper ide warn about a base type usage

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273941/php-case-sensitivity

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php . There's no System.string in PHP.

Answer (score -2):

string in php is not an object, which mean, you can't use method like equals or other that can be use in java.

string in php is a type as well as float, int ...